# How can I speed up select query with running totals?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a source table with about 45,000 rows. It has some detail, then a week number, as well as a Qty Planned and Qty Shipped for that week and line of detail. I am now trying to add running qty for both planned and shipped

I have written a query that works if I add a lot of WHERE clauses, but If I remove them, the query runs for a very long time.

```
SELECT

 s.Season
,s.CustomerCode
,s.Customer
,s.VarietyCode
,s.Variety
,s.GrowingMethodCode
,s.ProductSizeCode
,s.PackType
,s.Market
,s.Brand
,s.WeekNum
,s.Qty_Planned
,(SELECT

  SUM(Qty_Planned)

  FROM  [DataMiningImports].[Apples_Planned_vs_Shipped]
  WHERE WeekNum <= s.WeekNum
  AND   Season = s.Season
  AND   CustomerCode = s.CustomerCode
  AND   VarietyCode = s.VarietyCode
  AND   GrowingMethodCode = s.GrowingMethodCode
  AND   ProductSizeCode = s.ProductSizeCode
  AND   PackType = s.PackType
  AND   Market = S.Market
  AND   Brand = s.Brand
  ) AS Qty_Planned_Running

,s.Qty_Shipped

,(SELECT

  SUM(Qty_Shipped)

  FROM  [DataMiningImports].[Apples_Planned_vs_Shipped]
  WHERE WeekNum <= s.WeekNum
  AND   Season = s.Season
  AND   CustomerCode = s.CustomerCode
  AND   VarietyCode = s.VarietyCode
  AND   GrowingMethodCode = s.GrowingMethodCode
  AND   ProductSizeCode = s.ProductSizeCode
  AND   PackType = s.PackType
  AND   Market = S.Market
  AND   Brand = s.Brand
  ) AS Qty_Shipped_Running

FROM [DataMiningImports].[Apples_Planned_vs_Shipped] AS s

ORDER BY S.WeekNum
```

Comment: Show us your execution plan for a slow running query https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the sums in a subquery, which is *most likely* being run once for every row in the outer table.

Instead, try using a window function:

```
SELECT Season, 
       CustomerCode, Customer,
       VarietyCode, Variety,
       GrowingMethodCode, ProductSizeCode, PackType, Market, Brand, 
       WeekNum, Qty_Planned, 
       SUM(Qty_Planned) OVER(PARTITION BY Season, CustomerCode, VarietyCode, GrowingMethodCode, ProductSizeCode, PackType, Market, Brand ORDER BY WeekNum) AS Qty_Planned_Running, 
       SUM(Qty_Shipped) OVER(PARTITION BY Season, CustomerCode, VarietyCode, GrowingMethodCode, ProductSizeCode, PackType, Market, Brand ORDER BY WeekNum) AS Qty_Shipped_Running
FROM [DataMiningImports].[Apples_Planned_vs_Shipped]
ORDER BY WeekNum
```